# How can I download pdf before loading another view in laravel?

Tags: laravel

after completing a registration formular, when user clicks submit button, I want to first download a pdf and then redirect user to a view. Here is my code :

```
public function formularSave(Request $request) {
        if(!isset($_REQUEST['token'])) {
            abort(404);
        }

        $token = $_REQUEST['token'];

        $upd_app = Application::where('token', $token)->update([
            'status' => 22
        ]);

        
        $result = "Registration complete.";
        
        $html .= 'Some test code here
            <br>
            <p>Date: '.date('d.m.Y H:i:s').'</p>
        ';

        $pdf = PDF::loadHTML($html);
        $filename = substr(md5(uniqid().time()), 0, 17) . '.pdf';
        $pdf->save(storage_path().'/app/public/uploads/rezolutii/'.$filename);
        
        //code for download pdf HERE!!!! 

        
        return view('site.pages.registercomplete', compact('result'));

    }
```

How can I download the pdf, after I create it?

Comment: check this. might be helpful. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#downloading-files

Comment: But if I use return Storage::download($filename); the second return view('site.pages.registercomplete', compact('result')); won't be executed @xenooooo

Answer (score -1):

It's impossible on Laravel.
This will not work. Your browser operates on simple requests one goes out one comes in.

There is no way for browser to know if user finished downloading the file and saved it somewhere. The final response from browser if file to be downloaded, nothing can follow that as far as I understand.

Now I'm not sure how that can be handled in javascript but in pure html requests it will not work.

Check this https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/redirect-after-download